# dynamically fill <select> without all <option> showing simultaneously

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, html-select

I have a select anchor with id=antibiotic that is dynamically filled. Based on the selection I want to then dynamically fill the next listview with id=dose. The code below is working, but all of the option anchors dynamically selected for id=dose show at the same time. I've tried selecting one choice programatically and then refreshing to no avail. Any other ideas? I'm using jquery mobile.

```
<body>
    <select Onchange='changer($(this).val())' class="antibiotic" id="antibiotic"  data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="">Select Antibiotic</option>          
        <?php
            $hostname = "xxxx";
            $username = "xxxx";
            $dbname = "xxxx";
            $password = "xxxx";
            $usertable = "renalAdjust";
            $yourfield = "antimicrobial";   
            //Connecting to your database
            $link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");
            mysql_select_db($dbname);
            //Fetching from your database table.
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if ($result) {
                $antimicrobial = array();
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $name = $row["$yourfield"];
                    array_push($antimicrobial, $name);
                }
                mysql_close($link);
                $antimicrobial2 = array_unique($antimicrobial);                    
                foreach($antimicrobial2 as $item) {
                    $item2 = str_replace(" ","_", $item);
                    ?><option class='opt' value=<?php echo $item2 ?>><?php echo $item ?></option><?php
                }
            }?>   
            </select>     
            <select class="dose" id="dose"  data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="">Select Dose</option>
            </select>   
            <select id="Creatinine Clearance"  data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="">Select Creatinine Clearance</option>
            </select> 
    <script>
        function changer(val){
            var dataString = 'id='+ val.replace("_"," ","g");
            $.post("renalAdjust2.php", {id: dataString}, function(data){
                var doses = data.split("----");
                for (var i in doses){
                    $('<option>').val(doses[i]).text(doses[i]).appendTo('.dose');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>   
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide any example? Little bit compliacted

Comment: yeah, I have a select input (id=antibiotic) filled by my database. Based on that selection, another select input (id=dose) is filled dynamically. The code does fill the second select (id=dose) with the appropriate option anchors, but they are all appearing together simultaneously...that is to say that they all seem to be selected and there is no dropdown effect.

Comment: If I change data-native-menu="false" to data-native-menu="true" in the select anchor, it works perfectly...but it loses the mobile styling! What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

data-native-menu="false" works. On a mobile browser it still renders nicely...